# Overriding only Option Rotate for a specific Monitor while keeping other auto configuration values

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf

Nowadays Xorg infers the configuration automatically, and for most of my usecases it works perfectly!

I work on Passenger Information System software and now one bus has their monitors installed upside down.

I could circumvent it with: `xrandr --output HMDI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rotate inverted`

Except, that my software also uses `xrandr` to turn the screen off (`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off`) and back on (`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto`) when necessary via `exec` calls.
*But it goes through all connected devices and uses their actual device names instead. It's not a hardcoded `HDMI-1`.*

The trick here is that `--auto` by default uses the default configuration, and in this instance, the default is to have the screen in it's expected rotation, which due to it being installed upside-down is.. well... upside-down.

If I was to add the `xrandr --rotate` call on software bootup, it would tamper with other instances, that do not need this. And to solve it in software in this case is much too big of an effort, when I think the alternative could be to provide the *default* via Xorg configuration augmentation.
I could set up the augments by hand on each installation where the screens are installed in weird ways and leave software as generic as possible.

My idea is to add `Option "Rotate" "inverted"` to a config in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xx-HDMI-1-default-rotation.conf`.
*Again, the HDMI-1 would be swapped for the actual device name on each installation, this happens to be HDMI-1.*

**First problem:** I don't know if such a minimal augmentation is possible.
**Second problem:** I don't know if `xrandr --auto` would use that as it's default in such case.
**Third problem:** In this auto-configuration setup, I don't know how to hook up the augmentation because I don't know which `Identifier`'s to use.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "???" <-- what to use here, so I don't override other defaults inferred by Xorg?
    Device "???" <-- what to use here, so that it applies to devices found by Xorg?
    Option "Rotate" "inverted"
EndSection
```

The other way I can think of is to use `Xorg :0 -configure` and add my augmentations there, but in this case, I am not sure if the configuration will be valid and wouldn't tamper with anything else.

I am no X expert, and the `Xorg :0 -configure` call provides me with too much configuration parameters that my confidence of using it in production lowers dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after googling around, I found a way to minimalistically augment the Xorg auto-configuration (at least for `Monitor` section).

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-hdmi-1-default-rotation.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1" # Use the one reported by xrandr
    Option "Rotate" "inverted"
EndSection
```

I noticed in `Xorg.0.log` that this one got picked up, and yay **First problem** & **Third problem** can be solved in this way!

As for the **Second problem**: `xrandr --auto` seems to use information provided from hardware, and ignores the defaults set by the software.

So, the conclusion is, **this can't be done** as there is no way to solve **second problem** posed in question.